# finding point on line $1$ unit next from start point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I have a line passing through points $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$. Can I find next point on the same line thats $1$ unit away from Point $P_1(x_1,y_1)$? If yes, how can I find?

[image]

I just draw line at these points in reality it can be anywhere.

Given the following
\begin{gather*}
A(x_1,y_2)\\
B(x_2,y_2)\\
d = \text{distance from }A \text{ to }C,
\end{gather*}
I need to find $C(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is given by $P(t)=P_1+tv$, where $v$ is parallel to $P_2-P_1$. Taking $v$ to be of norm 1 allows you to take $P(1)$ as the point you seek. In other words, the point you seek is $$ P_1+ \frac{P_2-P_1}{\|P_2-P_1\|}$$
More generally, the point at distance $d$ from $P_1$ is
$$ P_1+ d\frac{P_2-P_1}{\|P_2-P_1\|}$$

Explicitly,
$$ x= x_1 + \frac{d}{n}(x_2-x_1), \quad  y= y_1 + \frac{d}{n}(y_2-y_1)$$
where $n = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

Comment: not sure how to solve this. What is P2? I dont know P2,P1. I have x,y values of Points P1 and P2. Sorry I have very very basic level of understanding in mathematic.

Comment: if A is (2.72, 5.24) and B is (-2.42, 1.54) and d is 1 how to get Cx and Cy?

Answer (score 2):

Find the distance between $B$ and $A$, call this $ {BA}$.

Find the distance between $C$ and $B$ (it's $  {BA}-d$), call this $ {CB}$.

Let the coordinates of $C$ be $(c_1,c_1)$.

Now use similar triangles:

$$
{\color{darkblue}{y_1-y_2}\over  {BA}}= {\color{darkgreen}{c_2-y_2}\over  {CB}}
$$

and

$$
{\color{maroon}{x_1-x_2}\over  {BA}}= {\color{orange}{c_1-x_2} \over {CB}}.
$$

Solve the above for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

---

[image]

Triangles  $\triangle ABa$  and    $\triangle CBc$
are similar. That is, they have the same angles. Thus, corresponding ratios of side lengths are equal:
$$\def\overline{}
{\overline{BC}\over\overline{ Bc}}={\overline{BA}\over\overline{ Ba}},\quad  {\overline{BC}\over\overline{ Cc}}={\overline{BA}\over\overline{ Aa}},\quad  {\overline{Bc}\over \overline{Cc}}={\overline{Ba}\over\overline{ Aa}}. 
$$

This is the same as saying the slope of a line can be computed using two arbitrary points on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$, we can find the equation of the line using [two-point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form), which is given by
$$\tag{1} y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1).$$

Now if $P=(x,y)$ is a point on the line, then of course $(x,y)$ satisfies (\ref{1}). Moreover, if $P$ is 1 unit away from $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$, then the distance between $P$ and $P_1$ is given by 
$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}=1.$$
Substitute $(1)$ into this, we get
$$(x-x_1)^2+\left[\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\right]^2=1,$$
which is a quadratic equation in $x$. By solving it, you can find the $x$-coordinate of $P$. After finding $x$, you can find the $y$-coordinate of $P$ by using $(1)$ again.